# ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (pyinit_ regex)

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to import regex package in Python. But I'm getting above error. I tried reinstalling the library. Still getting the same error.

Import regex

ImportError
Traceback (most recent call last)
 in

1 from ayx import Alteryx

```
  2
```

----> 3 import regex
c:\program files\alteryx\alteryx designer 2019.4\bin\miniconda3\envs\jupytertool_venv\lib\site-packages\regex_*init*_.py in

----> 1 from .regex import *

```
  2 from . import regex      3 __all__ = regex.__all__
```

c:\program files\alteryx\alteryx designer 2019.4\bin\miniconda3\envs\jupytertool_venv\lib\site-packages\regex\regex.py in 
417 # Internals.
418

--> 419 import regex._regex_core as _regex_core

```
420 import regex._regex as _regex

421 from threading import RLock as _RLock
```

c:\program files\alteryx\alteryx designer 2019.4\bin\miniconda3\envs\jupytertool_venv\lib\site-packages\regex_regex_core.py in

```
 19 from collections import defaultdict

 20
```

---> 21 import regex._regex as _regex

```
 22 

 23 __all__ = ["A", "ASCII", "B", "BESTMATCH", "D", "DEBUG", "E", "ENHANCEMATCH",
```

ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__regex)

Comment: Please share your code, full error message and all other info that might be helpful for us to see what is wrong

Comment: Updated the error